# Create two identical databases from one backup file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

For comparison purposes I'm trying to create two identical databases from one backup. The backup contains only one database.

Creating first database is going well.

When trying to create second database from the same backup file I get the error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Restore of database 'defaultDB' failed. However, the Tail-Log backup operation completed successfully.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\dbname.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'dbname'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60+((SQL11_RTM).120210-1917+)&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Do I have to change the mdf and ldf files to a new one?

Comment: Restore twice that is all. Use different names for DB and files.

Comment: if you have 2 mdf files just copy paste it

Comment: When restore for second time change path of mdf file then it works.

Comment: Please check  is there any open connection ton second data base or while restoring second database it is point same mdf and ldf file. However while restoring, once you select backups file please check under Option there are Restore as column with database file name is correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply uncheck the option about "Take tail-log backup before restore" in the Options screen. A tail-log backup is used typically for when you have a log file (LDF) but a corrupt data file (MDF). It does not apply here
2. In the Files screen, rename the files (or path if you want). Each DB will have it's own MDFs and LDFs. This will rename the files on restore to avoid a conflict

The error comes from point 2, but point 1 applies here too. Doing a log backup each time will give different data in restore because changes (DDL or data) that happen between log backups

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the path of the destination database i.e create a separate location and store the .mdf and .ldf files there, while creating the second identical database
2. Restore the identical database overwrite the second(with replace) under options tab